# Problem creating a pop-up alert before app requests location permission

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm a beginner programmer and Google sent me an email saying

> Your app must display a prominent disclosure through a pop-up alert
> before your app’s location runtime permission. Based on our review, a
> prominent disclosure did not appear before the runtime permission.
> Please add a prominent disclosure before the runtime permission.

I have tried a lot of things and just cant figure out how to popup an alert before the permissions. It always pops up up after the permissions.

Here is my MainActivity :

```
using Android;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Plugin.Permissions;

[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Manifest.Permission.LocationHardware)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = Manifest.Permission.Internet)]

namespace TqlSaldo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TqlSaldo", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]

    public class WebViewLocationActivity : Activity
    {
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults); base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
            }
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
            var webview = new WebView(this);
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webview.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);            
            webview.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
            
            webview.LoadUrl("https://clientescentro.tanquelleno.com/Mapa/IndexLimite");

            SetContentView(webview);
        }
    }





    public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {

        private readonly Context _context;

        public MyWebChromeClient(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public override void OnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(string origin, GeolocationPermissions.ICallback callback)
        {
            const bool remember = true;
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            builder.SetTitle("Localizador de Estaciones")
                .SetMessage(string.Format("Por favor acepta lalocalizacion:", origin))
                .SetPositiveButton("Aceptar", (sender, args) => callback.Invoke(origin, true, remember))
                .SetNegativeButton("Denegar", (sender, args) => callback.Invoke(origin, false, remember));
            var alert = builder.Create();
            alert.Show();
        }



    }






}
```

And here's a screenshot of the GPS popup.
[image: the permissions are running fine i just need help por the prominent disclosure BEFORE the ask of permisions]

The permissions are running fine, I just need help with the prominent disclosure BEFORE the ask of permissions

Comment: Use [Xamarin.Essentials Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android). If you read the docs it's pretty straightforward

Comment: I don’t think you need to show the disclosure as a popul alert. It’s only needed if you are using location in background. Do you need to use the location in the background?

Answer (score 3):

You are making a mistake by asking for permission inside your `OnCreate()` before the web view gets called. So, instead show the disclosure message first.
Basically, you just need to replace this

```
if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
{
    RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
}
```

with this

```
RequestLocationWithDisclosure();
```

And then just add these in your WebViewLocationActivity:

```
private void GetPermission()
{
    if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
    {
        RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
    }
}

private void RequestLocationWithDisclosure()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.SetTitle("GPS Disclosure");
    alert.SetMessage(string.Format("Por favor acepta lalocalizacion:", origin));
    alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, e) => { GetPermission(); });

    var dialog = alert.Create();
    dialog.Show();
}
```

---

The above answer is for Xamarin Native, Xamarin Forms users can just use the following. The Forms function does not have the ability to call another function after you hit ok, unlike native android. So you just have to call them separately:

```
await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("GPS Disclosure", "This app collects location data to provide GPS information to the XYZ Company portal even when the app is closed or not in use.", "OK");
```

And then call this code

```
_location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

`onGeolocationShowPrompt` doesn't actually show a prompt itself, it is just a method that gets called when the page requests your `Geolocation`.

About **Prominent Disclosure** ,you could look at [Google's Prominent Disclosure Requirement](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/google-prominent-disclosure-requirement/#In_App_Disclosure) and [User Data](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9888076#1&2&3&4&5&6&7&87&9).

And you could declared permissions and in-app disclosures follow the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0I1Xq_iSK4&vl=en).

Comment: i just need how to do the Prominent Disclosure; the permisions on the app are runing fine but  i cant achive to make the Prominent Disclosure BEFORE the permision goes in to display

Comment: @MierducciCastaneda As i said above,`onGeolocationShowPrompt` is just a method that gets called when the page requests your Geolocation.